# How to add edit and delete buttons in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am fairly new to data tables, I am trying to add edit and delete buttons to my data table on each row. Once clicked, the edit and delete buttons should execute some functions I created. I have tried reading documentations and other StackOverflow questions but I don't seem to get them. Here is my code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:fit-content; " id="mydatatable">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th data-field="Document_id" scope="col">Document id</th>
       <th scope="col">title</th>
       <th scope="col">details</th>
       <th scope="col">timestamp</th>
       <th scope="col">name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <th data-field="Document_id" scope="col">Document id</th>
       <th scope="col">title</th>
       <th scope="col">details</th>
       <th scope="col">timestamp</th>
       <th scope="col">name</th>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
```

```
db.collection("Emergency_Feeds").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {

    console.log('documents retrieved successfully');
    console.log(`is here: ${change.doc.id} => ${change.doc.data().name}`);

    var documentId = change.doc.id;
    var username = change.doc.data().name;
    var emTitle = change.doc.data().title;
    var emDets = change.doc.data().details;
    var emTimeDate = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate();

    if (change.type === "added") {
      tableData.push(
        [
          documentId,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          emTimeDate,
          username
        ]);
    }

    if (change.type === "modified") {
      //..... 
      //Here update the table element
      // Note that the DocumentChange contains the old and new index
      tableData.push(
        [
          documentId,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          emTimeDate,
          username
        ]);
    }

    if (change.type === "removed") {
      //..... 
      //Here remove the table element
      tableData.pop(
        [
          documentId,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          emTimeDate,
          username
        ]);
    }
  });

  $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
    retrieve: true,
    data: tableData,
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    lengthMenu: [
      [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
      [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],


  });
  $('#mydatatable tfoot th').each(function() {

    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />')
  });
  var datTable = $('#mydatatable').DataTable();
  datTable.columns().every(function() {

    var that = this;
    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {

      if (that.search() !== this.value) {

        that.search(this.value).draw();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you include a link on what you mean by "datatables"? An API perhaps that it would be easy to click on (per your question) without doing their own research? If to help you involves research and even if "datatables" is readily searchable, the version of such API/interface/framework helps greatly. Research often results to the latest version which you may not be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#mydatatable').DataTable({
retrieve: true,
data: tableData,
pagingType: 'full_numbers',
lengthMenu: [
  [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
  [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
],
 columns: [
        {
            data: "ID",
            render:function (data, type, row) {
             return `<button class='add' >add</button>`;        
        },
        {
            data: "ID",
            render:function (data, type, row) {
                    return `<button class='edit' >edit</button>`;
        },
        {
            data: "ID",
            render:function (data, type, row) {
                    return `<button class='delete' >delete</button>`;
        }
        ,
            //..... your remaining columns need to mention here...

  });



 $('#mydatatable .add').on('click',function(){ 
//.. your logic for add button click 
})

    $('#mydatatable .edit').on('click',function(){ 
//.. your logic for edit button click 
})

    $('#mydatatable .delete').on('click',function(){ 
//.. your logic for delete button click 
})
```

Comment: should the data:"ID" stay as it is ?

Comment: ID is the unique value in particular row, use that node from your json data

Comment: I am not using json , I am using an array, also the columns have already been specified in the html script

Comment: also does it mean that I have to give the columns in html ids?

Comment: could you share your 'tableData'?\

Comment: Check the javascript I have posted above, I am retrieving the data from Firestore database then setting the data into an array. Using the array Iam injecting the data into the datatable

Comment: use documentId in place of ID  whereever i have used

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined
    at pb (jquery.dataTables.min.js:40)
    at ja (jquery.dataTables.min.js:62)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:106)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:106)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.q [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:96)
    at k.fn.init.f.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:179)
    at Object.next (index.js:203)
    at next (database.ts:1973)

Comment: from where it is throwing

Comment: it worked, the buttons render, the problem was i did not add the other columns